# calling stored-procedures in mysql without passing values for columns with default values

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have a big table with at least 25 columns. The columns are all NN(Not Null) and 20 of them have default values. these values are long strings by themselves. So I decided to design the tables with proper default values. So if someone doesn't want other values won't need to insert them.

HERE is the main question:
For most cases user just needs to insert 5 new distinct values, but some times need to specify more values.
Now I have an stored-procedure with 25 arguments.

**How can I call the sp without specifying values for some of those 20 columns and just specify those needed?**

Comment: Well, do you really need the procedure? Would make sense maybe if you showed us the procedure.

Comment: can't show the procedure!!!
but I ensure the table is frequently changing and is target to a server... So yes we need the sp...

Comment: The table is frequently changing? Sounds like you should rethink some other parts of your application before you worry the number of parameters.